# JDBC connection pool with settings that vary by time of day

Tags: java, jdbc, persistence, connection-pooling

When configuring a connect pool library like Apache Commons DBCP, many of the settings depend on the anticipated performance characteristics. Many Java applications (web frontend or backend) have different performance characteristics depending on the time of day. Is there an implementation of something like DBCP's BasicDataSource, except it can have different profiles depending on the time of day?

Comment: Just configure it for the highest number of connections.

Comment: First, that doesn't answer the question. Second, in my case I did something like that but that's not an option anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring it for the highest number of connections is the best option but apparently you don't want to do that.

Another option is for you to "manage profiles" programatically. DBCP can be configured programatically so you can create/drop connection profiles based upon the time of the day.